# Unable to locate package libpng12 while installing Icinga

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install [icinga](https://www.icinga.org/) on my ubuntu machine. I am following the [quick start](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/quickstart-icinga.html) guide for doing the installation. When I run the command `apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev libpng12 libpng12-dev` I am getting an error message as :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpng12
```

Also when i run the command `apt-get install snmp libsnmp5-dev` I am geting error as :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsnmp5-dev
```

I am new to using Ubuntu and Icinga, I am not able to find where I have done mistake. Please help me in this.

Also I followed [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers) to install any missing compilers and ran the commands given in the site:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ gcc -v
$ make -v
```

But even after running the commands I am seeing same error messages.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libsnmp-dev
`

Comment: I'd not install from sources when deb packages are available, check their [Snapshot Builds](http://packages.icinga.org/debian/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enter the package names correctly.

Correct names of `libpng12` and `libsnmp5-dev` are `libpng12-0` `libsnmp-dev` respectively.

So the correct commands should be :

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev libpng12-dev libpng12-0

sudo apt-get install snmp libsnmp-dev
```